# Empty Import inspection window

Tags: jabref, import

I have trouble importing google scholar entries into the JabRef database.

1. I search for papers via the google scholar search window and select entries for the import
2. the newly open inspection inspection window is empty!!

I use JabRef version 3.5 on Windows 10.

Any ideas? Regards!

Comment: This was genuinely useful to me as I encountered the same bug, and the JabRef website points us here for help with it, perhaps this should be moved to stackoverflow since it's a bug with the application and not latex specific?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, there is a bug regarding the Google Scholar search in JabRef 3.5.
See: https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues/1639

This bug should be fixed in the development version, which you can find
here: http://builds.jabref.org/master/